# How to call the protocol between two independent uiview in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiview

i am declare the protocol in one UIView class i want to implement the protocol method in another UIView class.  but the protocol method does not call what can i do.  Any one Help me  [image: UPload UIview class]

[image: declaration]

[image]

[image: Implementation Uiview class]

[image: set the delegate respected view]

[image: Protocol implementation]

Comment: Please post sample code.

Comment: Hi maulik updated my questions

Comment: Your code looks right, check to see if `delegate` is not nil.

Comment: FYI when you include your code you shouldn't use images, you should put the code in your question as text.

Comment: hello skram how to check the delegate is not nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you call the delegate function in UploadView?
Also, since it is optional function, you have to check if the delegate response to the function before calling it.

```
- (void)yourFunction {
    ...
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(takeAnotherPhoto:)]) {
        [delegate takeAnotherPhoto:self];
    }
    ...
}
```