# How to call the protocol from another uiview in Iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

[My Question is similar to this Previously ask question please provide me some solution for this ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974850/how-to-call-the-protocol-between-two-independent-uiview-in-iphone)

**In my SettingView.h**

```
@protocol settingViewProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)getSelectedLanguageID:(NSInteger)langID;
@end

@interface SettingView : UIView<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
{

   NSMutableArray *settingElementArray;
   NSMutableArray *settingImageArray;
   UIPickerView *LanguagePickerView;
   NSArray *pickerArray;
   UIToolbar *toolBar;
}

@property (assign)id<settingViewProtocol> delegate;

  // in my SettingView.m

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    [self.delegate getSelectedLanguageID:row];
}
```

**//In my GrideView.h**

```
#import "SettingView.h"
@interface GrideView : UIView <AVAudioPlayerDelegate,settingViewProtocol>{

  MoreOptionView *moreOption;
  AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
  BOOL isPlaying;
  SettingView *settingView;

}
-(void)awakeFromNib
 {
   [super awakeFromNib];
   settingView = [[SettingView alloc]init];
   settingView.delegate = self;
}
```

but delegate returns nil value ??

Edit Code for more Info

**//In my ViewController**

```
self.settingView = (SettingView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([SettingView class]) owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
[self.settingView setFrame:CGRectMake(320*0, 0,bottomScrollView.frame.size.width, bottomScrollView.frame.size.height)];
self.settingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingbackground.png"]];
[self.bottomScrollView addSubview:self.settingView];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is correct.. But I suspect `awakeFromNib` is it getting called?

Comment: @Volker It is not same View it is GrideView

Comment: @iphonic Yes,awakeFromNib always call..

Comment: @Vishu is the settings view you are creating in wakeFromNib also displayed? or are you by mistake displaying another instance of settings view?

Comment: @Volker i am just calling the delegate of settingView in GrideView awakeFromNib method.. SettingView is already created by myviewController class..

Comment: @Vishu if settingView is already created, then use the already created setting view and assign self to that as delegate. In your code you create a new setting view in awakeFromNib

Comment: @Volker but i want it's protocol method on GrideView not in MyViewController class when i assign self to that as delegate it demands for protocol <settingViewProtocol> in viewController and that method also.

Comment: @Vishu i undertand what you want, but settingView = [[SettingView alloc]init]; creates a new instance. That you are delegate of. If your real settingsView is created someplace else, it will not work this way!

Comment: @Volker So please tell me what should i do for this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason because `delegate` property is nil - you instantiate two different objects.

You create one object here:

```
@interface GrideView : UIView <AVAudioPlayerDelegate,settingViewProtocol>

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
   [super awakeFromNib];
   settingView = [[SettingView alloc]init];
   settingView.delegate = self;
}
```

You create it and set `delegate`. And this object has value in `delegate` property.

Also you create **another** instance of `SettingView` here:

```
self.settingView = (SettingView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([SettingView class]) owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
[self.settingView setFrame:CGRectMake(320*0, 0,bottomScrollView.frame.size.width, bottomScrollView.frame.size.height)];
self.settingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingbackground.png"]];
[self.bottomScrollView addSubview:self.settingView];
```

This instance of `SettingView` does **not** have value in `delegate` property.

How can you resolve? You need to use all instance of `SettingView` over you view controller. For example if you have have property to `GrideView` in your view controller:

```
@interface ViewController
...
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GrideView *gridView;
...
@end
```

You can create `SettingView` in `-awakeFromNib` of `GrideView` and expose property with it for view controller:

```
@implementation GrideView 
...
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [super awakeFromNib];
   self.settingView = (SettingView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([SettingView class]) owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
   self.settingView.delegate = self;
}
...
@end
```

Create property with it in `interface` section:

```
@interface GridView : UIView
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) SettingView *settingView; // strong - because you want to keep it till view controller use it
...
@end
```

And you in view controller as property of `gridView`:

```
[self.gridView.settingView setFrame:CGRectMake(320*0, 0,bottomScrollView.frame.size.width, bottomScrollView.frame.size.height)];
self.gridView.settingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingbackground.png"]];
[self.bottomScrollView addSubview:self.gridView.settingView];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the setting view is already in your nib, and the grid view is already in your nib, then change the delegate property declaration to an IBOutlet:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet id<settingViewProtocol> delegate;
```

And make the delegate connection in interface builder. Remove your awakeFromNib method.

Your current code is making a new instance of the setting view and setting that view's delegate, but this isn't the view on the screen.

Comment: doesn't work I use this and when i apply breakpoints on it give struct_objeC_object * delegate 0x0 and when printing this it gives Printing description of delegate:
(null)

Comment: What doesn't work? Did it let you make the connection in interface builder?

Comment: Then you're going to have to edit your question with more details. How are you loading all this in the first place? Are you still initializing any of these views in code?

Answer (score 0):

It returns nil because you did not assign any object that confirm the settingViewProtocol to the delegate property.

Either you can set it in the xib file or you manually set it up by:
self.settingView.delegate = self;
And make sure that the VC you are using confirm the settingViewProtocol

One more thing is about awakeFromNib.
Perhaps the time you assign the self to the delegate, you gridView is not instantiated. It's just simply gotten awake from xib file. So, check whether the self is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In setting.h file

```
@protocol settingViewProtocol <NSObject>
```

-(void)getSelectedLanguageID:(NSInteger)langID;
@end

@interface SettingView : UIView
{

NSMutableArray *settingElementArray;
   NSMutableArray *settingImageArray;
   UIPickerView *LanguagePickerView;
   NSArray *pickerArray;
   UIToolbar *toolBar;
   id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,stronh)id delegate;

// in my SettingView.m

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getSelectedLanguageID:)]) //checking is delegate
        [self.delegate getSelectedLanguageID:row];

}

And now in your controller

-(void)awakeFromNib
 {
   [super awakeFromNib];
   if(!settingView)
       settingView = [[SettingView alloc]init];
   settingView.delegate = self;
   [self.view addsubview:settingView];
}

//then you can access
-(void)getSelectedLanguageID:(NSInteger)langID{} //in your controller file